# EnableViewState for html tag

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am quite new and I will like to ask a question. Please see the html and codebehind.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" runat="server" EnableViewState="True"></ul>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                var liItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                var aItem = new HtmlGenericControl("a");

                liItem.Attributes.Add("class", "test");
                aItem.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
                aItem.InnerText = "please work";
                liItem.Controls.Add(aItem);
                menu.Controls.Add(liItem);
            }
        }
```

Once postback, the UL data is lost though I have enabled the viewstate. I remember it works last time but now it is not. Anybody can advise? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are dynamically adding data via your first load (!`IsPostback`), and thereafter (when `Page_Load` runs again) the data is being lost. You have to keep in mind that `EnableViewState` is a ASP.NET specific property, So it will only work on server controls inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Control`

The only way you can achieve this is by either creating your html tags on each and every page load (i.e remove your `!IsPostBack` check)

or adding a ASP.NET control to the page which supports ViewState (Gridview, ListView, Label, Button etc).